# Is there a way to set overcommit memory in a Google Cloud notebook instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-iam

I've set up a jupyter notebook instance on the Google Cloud AI Platform and am able to see that the overcommit memory is set to 0 by using the command:
`cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`

However, when I try to set the memory to 1 by using the command: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`, it gives me the following error:
`bash: /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory: Permission denied`

I know that this is likely due to something in the IAM and changes would need to be made there, but exactly what policy do I need to add or alter to my current project so that I have permission to change the overcommit memory type?

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

I tried it in my instance and it works.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234114/trying-to-modify-proc-sys-vm-overcommit-memory-but-getting-permission-denied-e)